# Decode and unzip a Base64 encoded and Gziped compressed text

Tags: c#-4.0, base64, gzip

I am trying to read a text from XML node. The text is base 64 encrypted and Gzip compressed. I am trying in the following ways:

```
1. XmlNodeList nodeDebugs = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Debugs");

2.     if (nodeDebugs != null)
3.        {

4.            for (int i = 0; i < nodeDebugs.Count; i++)
5.             {
6.                 XmlNodeList childNodes = nodeDebugs.Item(i).ChildNodes;
7.                 String nodeName = childNodes.Item(i).Name;
8.                 if (nodeName == "Debug")
9.                 {  

10.                 byte[] compressed = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(childNodes.Item(i).InnerText.Trim());

11.  using (var uncompressed = new MemoryStream())
12.  using (var inStream = new MemoryStream(compressed))
13.  using (var outStream = new GZipStream(inStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
14.  {
15.      outStream .CopyTo(uncompressed);
16.      Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(uncompressed.ToArray()));
17.  }
```

Getting error at Line no 15, as "the magic number in gzip header is not correct."
Any help to resolve this issue is much appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Your code doesn't use base64 anywhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem, I suspect:

```
byte[] compressed = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(childNodes.Item(i).InnerText.Trim());
```

You said that your data is compressed and then base64-encoded... but your code doesn't use base64 anywhere, which is a massive warning sign. I suspect you want:

```
string text = childNodes.Item(i).InnerText.Trim();
byte[] compressed = Convert.FromBase64String(text);
```

If that *doesn't* work, you should check each step of the transformation - you should have the same data during encoding and decoding, just in the reverse order. See my [blog post about diagnosing reversible data transformations](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/01/20/diagnosing-issues-with-reversible-data-transformations/) for more details - but hopefully the change above will fix it anyway.

Comment: Thanks It works..But one more question I am getting O/P as "�\b\0\0\0\0\0\0Ľk��ƒ �Y��ؘX{���z:�n�,ɏ�ek��xϞ�`�\0؍�|\t ��_3�\n(\0$�s.Cb�\0*3++��|����͛ " Any idea how to get back original decoded string? I am trying with this  var reader = new StreamReader(uncompressed);
                                uncompressed.Position = 0;
                                string myStr = reader.ReadToEnd();

Comment: @Anand: I've no idea what you mean by "O/P" in this case, but that looks like binary data, which you shouldn't be reading with a `StreamReader` (that's designed for text). If that doesn't help enough, I suggest you ask a new question with more details. (Don't just add more comments here.)